# pandas dataframe not able to update rows values for column name that contains brackets and comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe has column (Employment_period,) **The column name includes brackets and comma**

```
column name: **(Employment_period,)**   
values in five rows are 
0,
1,
1,
0,
1
```

I am trying to update rows in this column based on this condition

```
df.loc[df["(Employment_period,)"] == 1,"(Employment_period,)"] = "Employment_period__1"
```

If row value is 1 then replace/update the row value to Employment_period__1

its not working for this column, I am getting KeyError
whereas the same code is working fine for other column name "city"

How should I select and update the value for this column?

Comment: Would you include also the output from `df.columns`?

Comment: The comma and the parantheses shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Comment: The error i am getting is KeyError: '(Employment_period,)'